# How to use ada boosting as an ensemble method in R?

Tags: r, classification, random-forest, ensemble-learning, adaboost

I am trying to learn ensemble methods and came across that ada-boosting can be built on top of the ordinary machine learning methods such as Random forest. the method can use the misclassified data in training set to build more accurate classification models.

However, I searched online but I couldn't find answers for the implementation.

I am wondering how to build a ada-boosting on top of a random forest for a classification problem to minimize the errors?

let's just say I have a

training set(df): Train

test set(df): Test

and a number of features called: Feature.

and the classifier is called: Outcome (Train$Outcome)

my normal model would be(assuming using caret package):

mymodel_rf<-train(Train[,Outcome], Train[,Feature], method ="rf", trControl= ...)

Then how to move forward? to build the ada-boosting methods using the outcome of this?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a proper method for ADAboost training, look here for a complete set: http://topepo.github.io/caret/train-models-by-tag.html Refer to this page for any model and find them by tag.

```
AdaBoost Classification Trees
method = 'adaboost'
Required packages: fastAdaboost
```

This method is the ADAboost on decision trees.